# Any suggestion or solution to my problem to inject selected list items from dropdownlist to other table in php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Working on a small image gallery project in php and mysql. The project has two table. Album (albumId and albumName) and gallery(id, imageName, albumId, img_name). So, when user need to create a image gallery, they need to input all the information like title, album name, and image. I am able to do most of the part, the section I was stuck was with inserting the dropdown list, which in my case is album. Here is my add_photo.php

```
<!--Adding Post Area-->    
    <form action="add_photo_check.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <?php
          if(isset($_SESSION['message']))
          {
              echo $_SESSION['message'];
              unset($_SESSION['message']);
          }
          ?>
       <!--Form for post-->
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="posttitle">
             <h5>Photo Title</h5>
          </label>
          <textarea name="imageName" class="form-control" placeholder="photo title.." ></textarea>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="album">Select Album</label>
           <select class="form-control" name="albumId" id="album">
               <option>Select Album</option>
          <?php
             $sql = "select * from album";
              $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);      
              while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                  echo"<option value=\"" .$row['albumId'] . "\" >" .$row['albumName']."</option>\n";
              }

             ?>
              </select>
              </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="uploadimage">
                <h5>Upload image</h5>
             </label>
             <div class="btn">
                <input type="file" name="image">
             </div>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Publish" name="publish" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
    </div>
```

This is my function file add_photo_check.php

```
<?php
include "includes/header.php";
if(isset($_POST['publish']))

{
  $title=$_POST['imageName'];
  $title=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$imageName);
  $title=htmlentities($imageName);

  $id=$_POST['albumId'];
  $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$albumId);
  $id=htmlentities($albumId);


  $uploadOk = 1;
    $img_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $errorMessage = "";

    if($img_name != "") {
        $targetDir = "images/upload/";
        $img_name = $targetDir . uniqid() . basename($img_name);
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($img_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);



    if(strtolower($imageFileType) != "jpeg" && strtolower($imageFileType) != "png" && strtolower($imageFileType) != "jpg") {
      $_SESSION['message']="<div class='alert alert-danger'>  Sorry, only jpeg, jpg and png files are allowed!</div>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if($_FILES['image']['size'] > 100000){
      $_SESSION['message']="<div class='alert alert-danger'> Image is too big to upload!</div>";
      header("Location: add_photo.php");

      }

    if($uploadOk) {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $img_name)) {
                //image uploaded okay
            }

      $sql="insert into gallery (title, id, img_name) value('$imageName','$albumId', '$img_name')";
      $res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      if($res)
      {
      $_SESSION['message']="<div class='alert alert-success'> Post Successfuly Published</div>";
      header("Location: add_photo.php");
      }
      else
      {
        $_SESSION['message']="<div class='alert alert-danger'> Something went wrong!</div>";
        header("Location: add_photo.php");
      }
    }
  } 

}

?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I accept that from time to time wheels need to be reinvented, but why this one, and why now?

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks :(